# State change should change style of one comp and hide another, how?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an Icon, call it Icon A, that needs to change and when tapped. Also when it's tapped, 2 other Icons need to appear. Let's call them Icon X and Icon Y.

When I tap Icon X, I want Icon X to change styles and Icon Y to disappear. Same if I tap Icon Y. I feel like I'm approaching this the wrong way and I don't want to use too many if/else statements.

Would love some guidance or recommendations so I don't drive myself too crazy here. Thanks! Here's some code I've been trying to work with:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    iconAClicked: false,
    iconXClicked: false,
    iconYClicked: false,
  }

  setXYVisible(){this.setState({iconAClicked: !this.state.iconAClicked})}

  setXClicked(){this.setState({iconXClicked: !this.state.iconXClicked})}

  setYClicked(){this.setState({iconYClicked: !this.state.iconYClicked})}

  render(){

    const iconAnotClicked = (
      <View> {iconNotA} </View>
    )

    const iconAClicked = (
      <View> {iconA} </View>
    )

    const iconXnotClicked = (
      <View> {iconNotX} </View>
    )
    const iconXClicked = (
      <View> {iconX} </View>
    )
    const iconYnotClicked = (
      <View> {iconNotY} </View>
    )
    const iconYClicked = (
      <View> {iconY} </View>
    )

    return (
      <View>

        {this.state.iconAClicked ?
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setXClicked()}>
              {this.state.iconXClicked : iconXClicked ? iconXnotClicked}
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setYClicked()}>
              {this.state.iconYClicked : iconYClicked ? iconYnotClicked}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          : null
        }

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.clickedXYVisible()}>
        {this.state.iconAClicked : iconAClicked ? iconAnotClicked}
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    )


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is almost good for reactjs.

However, your Y icon won't disappear in this situation. To toggle a component easily you can process this way: **`{ this.state.isDisplayed && <component>}`**, which is more elegant than `{ this.state.isDisplayed ? <component> : null }` you are using.

Moreover, you have duplicate logic, indeed, your `iconAClicked` and `iconAnotClicked` are just `<View>` with a different content. You should either create a function `iconX`, or place the `<View>` directly in your render.

To match your logic, this gives:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       iconAClicked: false,
       iconXClicked: false,
       iconYClicked: false
    }

    setXYVisible(){this.setState({iconAClicked: !this.state.iconAClicked})}
    setXClicked(){this.setState({iconXClicked: !this.state.iconXClicked})}
    setYClicked(){this.setState({iconYClicked: !this.state.iconYClicked})}

    render(){

        return (
          <View>
            { this.state.iconAClicked &&
              <View>
                { !this.state.iconYClicked && 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setXClicked()}>
                        <View> {this.state.iconXClicked : iconX ? iconNotX} </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                { !this.state.iconXClicked &&  
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setYClicked()}>
                        <View> {this.state.iconYClicked : iconY ? iconNotY} </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
              </View>
            }

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.clickedXYVisible()}>
                 <View> {this.state.iconAClicked : iconA ? iconNotA} </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Using functions instead of constants:

```
    displayXIcon(){return (<View>{ this.state.iconXClicked ? iconX : iconNotX }</View>)}
    displayYIcon(){return (<View>{ this.state.iconYClicked ? iconY : iconNotY }</View>)}
    displayAIcon(){return (<View>{ this.state.iconAClicked ? iconA : iconNotA }</View>)}

    render(){

        return (
          <View>

            {this.state.iconAClicked ?
              <View>
                { !this.state.iconYClicked && 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setXClicked()}>
                        {this.displayXIcon()}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                { !this.state.iconXClicked &&  
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setYClicked()}>
                        {this.displayYIcon()}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
              </View>
              : null
            }

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.clickedXYVisible()}>
                {this.displayAIcon}
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
        )


    }
```